# get rid of + between words while searching

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm doing an iOS application where the user insert a movie title
and the application tells the user the plot and actor and display an image for the movie.
The database is http://www.omdbapi.com/
The application works fine but with movies with 2 words 
i must insert a `+` to make it work (is there a way to fix that..)

`OMDB` is a class with parameters actors and plot and image

```
public func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
    let searchtext=searchBar.text
           getData(withTitle: searchtext!)
            {

                (result: String?, data: Omdb?, error: String?) in
                if result == "Success"
                {
                    self.tempOmdb = data!
                    self.tableview.reloadData()

                                         }
                else{
                    print(error)
                }
            }

}
```

Comment: add that code where you added + .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the spaces with plusses.

```
let modifiedSearchText = searchtext.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
```

So here is your updated code (I also cleaned it up a little):

```
public func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    guard let searchtext = searchBar.text else { return }
    let modifiedSearchText = searchtext.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    getData(withTitle: modifiedSearchText) { (result: String?, data: Omdb?, error: String?) in
        if result == "Success" {
            self.tempOmdb = data!
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```